# Twitter streaming API not responding on production, but OK on dev server

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twython

I have been listening to the Twitter public stream with Twython with no problem but the production server stopped receiving any tweets for a couple of days.

I've created a simple test case:

```
>>> from twython import TwythonStreamer
>>> 
>>> class TestStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
...     def on_success(self, data):
...         print data
... 
>>> stream = TestStreamer(KEY, SECRET, TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET)
>>> 
>>> stream.statuses.filter(track='clinton,trump')
```

This snippet runs on the development server. Tweets instantly start flowing in. On production it again seems to be listening, there are no errors thrown, but no tweets.

I thought it might be the *firewall* on the server, or the server might be *blacklisted* on Twitter's side. But when I try the same query with **curl** command generated by the Twitter signature generator dev tool, with the same token set, the command starts receiving tweets instantly **both on the development and production servers** without any problem. I think this curl test eliminates these firewall, blacklist or token issues options.

What do you think the problem might be? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be **server clock drift** on the **AWS EC2** servers that caused the authentication to fail due to the usage of an expired timestamp. It was also **Twython** suppressing the exception which made the case more obscure.

I tried with the Twitter client **Birdy** and get the "Unauthorized" response. Then I came across [this post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-streaming-connection-perfectly-working-on-dev-server-but-not-on-production/7664).

So I made a clock sync and everything is back to normal again:

```
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Answer (score 1):

To give more insight over the problem and your solution, I would like people to note that Twitter Authentication mechanism uses OAuth which requires the DateTime of the query to be provided as part of any request header (`oauth_timestamp`).

When Twitter receives the query they will verify that the `oauth_timestamp` is not too old or not invalid. When they have done that they will verify the `oauth_signature`.

Most libraries will use the current machine DateTime and use it to create their request. Therefore when using a Third Party tool to access the Twitter API ensure that the DateTime of the machine is correctly setup.

Some more advanced libraries will allow you to specify a function that will be invoked to access the DateTime. This is particularly useful if your software is distributed to machines for which you cannot ensure the validity of the DateTime.

I hope this makes some sense.